# How to pass a URL parameter in get_queryset method in Django REST View?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to pass an ID to a URL in Django to filter my results. For simplicity, I want to list all **Foo** that are related to a **Bar** object. I can filter this since **Foo** has foreign key relationship with **Bar**.

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('bar/<int:bar_pk>/foo/', FooListView.as_view()),
]
```

In my View, I place the ID as parameter to `get_queryset()` method. However it is not passed down. Can this method not accept URL parameters?

```
class FooListView(ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = FooSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
    pagination_class = StandardResultsSetPagination
        
    def post(self, request, bar_pk):
        pass

    def get_queryset(self, bar_pk):
        bar = Bar.objects.get(pk=bar_pk)

        foos = Foo.objects.filter(
            bar=bar).order_by('-id')
        return foos
```

I receive this error.

```
get_queryset() missing 1 required positional argument: 'bar_pk'
```

How can I pass the URL parameter such that I get a filtered result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is in the `self.kwargs`, so:

```
class FooListView(ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = FooSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
    pagination_class = StandardResultsSetPagination
        
    def post(self, request, bar_pk):
        pass

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Foo.objects.filter(bar_id=self.kwargs['bar_pk']).order_by('-id')
```

Comment: I see. I did not see that in the docs. Thank you!